# Find the latter date in an object

Tags: javascript

I need iterate specific objects in an object, and find the object with latter Date.

Here is example of my object:

```
var o = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "category": "test1",
      "parents": [
        {
          "id": 31,
          "children": [
            {
              "firstName": "Steve",
              "lastName": "Martin",
              "created": "2018-04-06T22:00:00.000Z"
            },
            {
              "firstName": "Steve2",
              "lastName": "Martin2",
              "created": "2016-02-10T23:00:00.000Z"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 31,
          "children": [
            {
              "firstName": "Julia",
              "lastName": "Robbery",
              "created": "2015-01-06T23:00:00.000Z"
            },
            {
              "firstName": "Nikol",
              "lastName": "Surachenko",
              "created": "2017-04-06T22:00:00.000Z"
            },
            {
              "firstName": "Nikol",
              "lastName": "Surachenko",
              "created": "2011-06-05T22:00:00.000Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried this:

```
var latter = null;
for (var i = 0; i < o.data[0].parents.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < o.data[0].parents[i].children.length; j++) {
        if (latter == null || moment(latter) < moment(o.data[0].parents[i].children[j].created))
            latter=o.data[0].parents[i].children[j].created;
    }
}
```

Can you tell me if exist some prettier way? For example with lambda, etc.?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: I removed "JSON" from your question, because there's no json here.

Comment: "prettier way" is very subjective....

Comment: Also, what do you mean by largest date?  The most recent? Largest sum of numbers in date?

Comment: The date 14 billion years ago is smallest, heat death of universe is largest

Comment: @chrisz latter date .. I fix it in question

Comment: So look at reduce and forEach and look at ways where you are not calculating the same moment value over and over again. And when you are done thinking it looks pretty, you better make sure that the "pretty" way is actually not hurting the performance.

Comment: @georg why this is not json?

Comment: Json is  _string_ format, like `'{"foo":"bar"}'`. Anything that's not a string, is not json, it's just a plain javascript object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"pretty" is subjective, but in my opinion with lodash you could write it in a bit cleaner way:

```
mostRecent = _.max(
    _.flatMap(
        _.get(o, 'data.0.parents'),
        'children'),
    'created')
```

If lodash is not an option, you can roll out your own ad-hoc microframework:

```
let get = p => o => o[p];
let flatMap = (a, f) => [].concat(...a.map(f));
let max = (a, f) => a.map(x => [x, f(x)]).reduce((m, p) => m[1] > p[1] ? m : p)[0];

mostRecent = max(
    flatMap(o.data[0].parents, get('children')),
    get('created')
)
```

Comment: **In spanish:** Que locura es esta!! :-)

Comment: @JonasW. According to google translator: Des einen Freud ist des **anderen** Leid.  Give me an upvote :-)

Comment: @ele haha well. I admit that its officially *anderen*, however thats difficult to spell so thats why you actually say *andren*. After the "neue deutsche Rechtschreibreform" this is actually valid to write :) [have a look in the Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/andre)

Answer (score 1):

Using `for-loops` and compare dates.

*This approach downstreams into the whole object to get the right object.*

```js
var o = {   "data": [{     "id": 2,     "category": "test1",     "parents": [{         "id": 31,         "children": [{             "firstName": "Steve",             "lastName": "Martin",             "created": "2018-04-06T22:00:00.000Z"           },           {             "firstName": "Steve2",             "lastName": "Martin2",             "created": "2016-02-10T23:00:00.000Z"           }         ]       },       {         "id": 31,         "children": [{             "firstName": "Julia",             "lastName": "Robbery",             "created": "2015-01-06T23:00:00.000Z"           },           {             "firstName": "Nikol",             "lastName": "Surachenko",             "created": "2017-04-06T22:00:00.000Z"           },           {             "firstName": "Nikol",             "lastName": "Surachenko",             "created": "2011-06-05T22:00:00.000Z"           }         ]       }     ]   }] }

var result = {};
for (var obj of o.data) {
  for (var p of obj.parents) {
    for (var c of p.children) {
      result = !result.created || Date.parse(c.created) > Date.parse(result.created) ? c : result;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Definetly more readable than the old style for loops in the OPs code. But that ternary? Wouldnt it be easier to do `var result = {}` , then you can leave away one ternary part...

Answer (score 0):

You might do it a bit more functional:

```
 const result = o.data[0].parents.reduce((res, {children}) => res.concat(children), [])
  .reduce((old, curr) => Date(old.created) > Date(curr.created) ? old : curr);
```

Comment: If you have more than one object in `data` this won't work.

Comment: That's true, just a comment :-)